# Why is it dangerous?

Tags: c, inheritance

I don't understand some topic from book Extreme C on page 300. It's about "multiple inheritance".

```
typedef struct { ... } a_t;
typedef struct { ... } b_t;

typedef struct {
    a_t a;
    b_t b;
    ...
} c_t;

c_t c_obj;
a_t* a_ptr = (a_ptr*)&c_obj;
b_t* b_ptr = (b_ptr*)&c_obj; //it's the problem
c_t* c_ptr = &c_obj;
```

Why we should do something like that??

```
c_t c_obj;
a_t* a_ptr = (a_ptr*)&c_obj;
b_t* b_ptr = (b_ptr*)(&c_obj + sizeof(a_t)); //?Is the address a_ptr the same as address c_obj?
c_t* c_ptr = &c_obj;
```

Thank you very much for all your help.

Comment: Because you are only allowed to treat a pointer to a struct like a pointer to its first member. The first member of `c_t` is a `a_t`, not a `b_t`

Comment: "Why we should do...?" We should not. There might be padding required for `b` which is not included in `sizeof a`. You could do `&c_obj.b` or `((char*)&c_obj)+offsetof(c_t,b)`

Comment: Especially we should not do `&c_obj + sizeof(a_t)` because that will do pointer arithmetics which will clearly not do what you want

Comment: Indent your code before posting. This is very confusing.

Comment: Besides, it does not even compile so I don't know what to say

Comment: C doesn't have "inheritance". It can be *emulated* by making the first member of a child structure be an object of the parent structure. But since it's only the first member, it's not possible to emulate multiple inheritance.

Comment: So what &c_obj + sizeof(a_t) do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why we should do...?

We should not do this!

First, `sizeof a` might be wrong to advance the address. If `b_t` as larger alignment requirements than `a_t` this will not yield the correct offset.

Second, the expression is wrong:

```
(&c_obj + sizeof(a_t))
```

This will take address of `c_obj` which has type `c_t*`. Then it will add a multiple of `sizeof (c_t)` which again points to object of type `c_t` but with an address that is illegal.

Third: Your casts are all wrong. You need to use name of a type, not a variable.

---

If you want to get address of `b`, there is a macro in C lib available `offsetof`:

```
offsetof(c_t,b)
```

evaluates to the offset in bytes of member `b` inside type `c_t`.
Then you can apply this to your address:

```
b_ptr=(b_t*)  ((unsigned char*)&c_obj) + offsetof(c_t,b));
```

The first cast to `unsigned char` is required to use byte arithmetics.

Of course, there is a much simpler way to do this:

```
b_ptr=&c_obj.b;
```

---

Maybe the point of the book was to show that you cannot just use address of a struct and cast it to a pointer to another struct but you have to take care about the location of the members inside that struct. That is correct.
But the dirty details were a bit off.

Comment: https://books.google.pl/books?id=G0C7DwAAQBAJ&pg=PA301&lpg=PA301&dq=b_t*+b_ptr+%3D+(b_ptr*)(%26c_obj+%2B+sizeof(a_t));+why&source=bl&ots=B-h4hh_AK2&sig=ACfU3U27VhuaoJ4-OTQOQBFeW5OaynAfNQ&hl=pl&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjmlqrnzqnrAhUB_qQKHS0DAqsQ6AEwAHoECAEQAQ#v=onepage&q=b_t*%20b_ptr%20%3D%20(b_ptr*)(%26c_obj%20%2B%20sizeof(a_t))%3B%20why&f=false

Comment: I don't know if I can paste the link but i did it :). There exist possibility  that I have misunderstood something.

Comment: well, that's clearly wrong in that snippet. They did not take into account that pointer arithmetics is applied.

Answer (score 1):

Keep it simple:

```
c_t c_obj;
a_t* a_ptr = &c_obj.a;
b_t* b_ptr = &c_obj.b;
c_t* c_ptr = &c_obj;
```

The problem with:

```
b_t* b_ptr = (b_ptr*)&c_obj;//it's the problem
```

is that `b_ptr` ends up pointing to `c_obj.a`.

The problems with:

```
b_t* b_ptr = (b_ptr*)(&c_obj + sizeof(a_t));//?Is the address a_ptr the same as address c_obj?
```

are:

1. You are trying to adjust the pointer by `sizeof(a_t)` bytes, but pointer arithmetic is scaled by the size of the dereferenced type of the pointer. In this case, the pointer type is `c_t*` (from the expression `&c_obj`), and the dereferenced type is `c_t`, so the pointer is actually being adjusted by `sizeof(c_t) * sizeof(a_t)` bytes.
2. There may be *padding* after some of the members of `c_t`. In particular, there may be padding between the `a` and `b` members, so the `b` member may not be at the offset that you think it is. The offset of `b` from the start of `c_t` in bytes can be determined using the expression `offsetof(c_t, b)`.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I am trying to verify the knowledge from the book.

Comment: @Kris_Holder So it's an error in the book. I guess the author got a bit sloppy at that point and didn't check the code properly.

Answer (score 1):

The address of an object of a structure type is equal to the address of the first member of the structure type.

So using your example

```
typedef struct {
a_t a;
b_t b;
...
} c_t;

c_t c_obj;
a_t* a_ptr = (a_ptr*)&c_obj;
```

then indeed the address of the data member `a` is equal to the address of the object `c_obj`.

However for the data member `b` this relation is broken because the data member `b` is not the first data member of the structure `c_t`.

As for this statement

```
b_t* b_ptr = (b_ptr*)(&c_obj + sizeof(a_t));
```

then it is entirely wrong. For starters in this sub-expression `&c_obj + sizeof(a_t)` there is used the pointer arithmetic and the value of the expression `&c_obj` is incremented by the value `sizeof( c_t ) * sizeof( a_t )` .

It seems you mean

```
b_t* b_ptr = (b_ptr*)(( char * )&c_obj + sizeof(a_t));
```

However in any case the expression in the right side in general will not yield the address of the data member `b` due to a possible alignment,

Consider the following demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct A
{
    int x;
};

struct B
{
    double y;
};

struct C
{
    struct A a;
    struct B b;
};

int main(void) 
{
    struct C c = { { 1 }, { 2.2 } };
    
    printf( "&c.a = %p\n( char * )( &c.c ) + sizeof( struct A ) = %p\n&c.b = %p\n",
            ( void * )&c.a, ( void * ) ( ( char * )&c.a + sizeof( struct A ) ), ( void * )&c.b );
    return 0;
}
```

Its output might look like

```
&c.a = 0x7ffe5e0697c0
( char * )( &c.c ) + sizeof( struct A ) = 0x7ffe5e0697c4
&c.b = 0x7ffe5e0697c8
```

As you see the data member `a` was appended with bytes to align the next data member `b` to double.